# Android: Best practice to ensure that a UI operation is done on UI thread

Tags: java, android, ui-thread, android-runonuithread

I have landed into situations where I need to do some the same UI operation (let's say showing of a `Toast` message) from two different threads. The difference is that the first thread is the UI thread for the activity and the other one is a separate thread that I started to run some background process. The question is that what is the best practice to ensure that the code to show the `Toast` message is always run from the UI thread. I see here two possibilities.

We have a function which is supposed to show the test message like

```
private void showToast() {
     Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And each time we call this method we ensure that it has to be called on the UI thread for which we can use `runOnUiThread()`from the place we are calling `showToast()`.

The other option is to ensure that the code to show the `Toast`is run on the `UI thread` within the method `showToast()` itself. SOmething like this:

```
private void showToast() {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Which is the preferred practice and why?

Comment: Why not use the second option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android updating ui thread elements - best practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635062/android-updating-ui-thread-elements-best-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second option. If you are already on the UI-Thread the action is just executed in the same context. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to determine if we currently are on UI thread then I recommend to do this such way :

```
Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()
```

This will return true if we are on UI thread.
Otherwise you can search more deeply in this direction :
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the second option is a useful but the Android patterns recommend to use an AsyncTask thread when you are working with threads because you have 3 different ways to use UI thread (onPreExecute, onProgressUpdates and onPostExecute).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html